# How to achieve a specific format using DateTime in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

Given a date "30/10/13 Wed" where the format is "dd/mm/yy {Day in words - 3 letters only}", is there a way using DateTime type that can output this kind of format?

I've looked and researched a little on MSDN's documentation of properties of DateTime and founded without no answer to what I am looking. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How hard did you look? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: Not too much, I admit that I've search a little only. Thanks for the link you've provided it was also the one I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 6, 11);
string result = dateValue.ToString("dd/MM/yy ddd");
```

will give you the result you want, read here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762911.aspx

Comment: Thanks lostincomputer2. It was a a big help. Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
Console.Write(DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy ddd"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for.

```
    DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy ddd");
```

You can use this to refer to datetime formatting. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx